# Force parsing optional groups

Tags: regex, option-type, regex-group

I'm trying to make a regex string that extracts data from report files. The tricky part is that I need this single regex string to match multiple report file content formats. I want the regex to always match even if some optional groups are not found.

Take the following report files content (**Note**: #2 is missing the "val2" part.):

> - File #1: "**-val1-test-val2-result-val3-done-**"

- Expected Result:

  - Val1 Group: **test**
  - Val2 Group: **result**
  - Val3 Group: **done**
- File #2: "**-val1-test-val3-done-**"

  - Expected Result:

    - Val1 Group: **test**
    - Val2 Group: (empty)
    - Val3 Group: **done**

I tried the following regex strings :

```
Regex #1(Normal): "-val1-(?<val1>.+?)-val2-(?<val2>.+?)-val3-(?<val3>.+?)-"
```

**Problem**: File #1 works fine but on file #2, the regex is not matching so I don't have any group values.

```
Regex #2(Non greedy)): "-val1-(?<val1>.+?)(-val2-(?<val2>.+?))?-val3-(?<val3>.+?)-"
Regex #3(Boolean OR): "-val1-(?<val1>.+?)(-val2-(?<val2>.+?)|(.*?))-val3-(?<val3>.+?)-"
Regex #4(Conditional): "-val1-(?<val1>.+?)(?(-val2-(?<val2>.+?))|(.+?))-val3-(?<val3>.+?)-"
Regex #5(Conditional): "-val1-(?<val1>.+?)(?(-val2-(?<val2>.+?))(-val2-(?<val2>.+?)))-val3-(?<val3>.+?)-"
Regex #6(Conditional): "-val1-(?<val1>.+?)(?(-val2-(?<val2>.+?))(-val2-(?<val2>.+?))|(.+?))-val3-(?<val3>.+?)-"
```

**Problem**: File #2 works as expected but the val2 group of file #1 is always empty.

**Conclusion**: The behavior seems to be that even if an optional group is present, the regex will prioritize an empty group value over the present value. Is there a way to force getting the optional groups' value when they are present and only return (empty) when they're not?

**Note**: I'm using the latest .NET framework and the code will ported to Java(Android). I'm trying to avoid using multiple operations for performance and bandwidth concerns.

Anyone could help me on this?

Comment: Do you think making the third value optional is also a valid approach for you? Have a look at [`-val1-(?<val1>.+?)(-val2-(?<val2>.+?))?(-val3-(?<val3>.+?))?-`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-val1-(%3f%3cval1%3e.%2b%3f)(-val2-(%3f%3cval2%3e.%2b%3f))%3f(-val3-(%3f%3cval3%3e.%2b%3f))%3f-&i=-val1-test-val2-result-val3-done-%0d%0a-val1-test-val3-done-&o=n).

Comment: in C#, in the test program I ran, Regex #5 is working for both file1 and file2. Is that not what you are getting?

Comment: Turns out my simplified example is not realistic enough. Here is a better one (based on html content extraction): https://regex101.com/r/jY4jK1/2 ; I set the 3 last groups to be optional and the result is that they don't get extracted, any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: You are asking the regex engine to care about matching data that it doesn't have sufficient information to know it needs to care about. You almost certainly need to switch to using HTML parsing and then potentially use regexes in conjuction with document tree queries.

Comment: I was trying to extract all information at once on a single process but I think XPaths might be a little more flexible and safe. Let's hope extracting infos one by one using this technique won't be dragging the performance down! :-) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if we make some assumptions:

1. values might be missing, but they are always in the same order
2. the first value is always present
3. there is a delimiter before and after the part we are looking for

```
-val1-([^-]+)(?:-val2-([^-]+)|)(?:-val3-([^-]+)|)-
```

https://regex101.com/r/yY6vF9/1

Comment: Hum... well, my example was a little too simplified... Could you get a look at this one instead? https://regex101.com/r/mI5uI0/1 . The first 2 groups will always be present, all the groups will be in the same order and as you can see, there is some html code that can be used as delimiters. The issue now is that if the "Time1" group is not present (I added a "notpresent" in the example), the whole regex is'nt matching anymore. Could you show me how to adapt you solution to this situation?

Comment: It is the same principle https://regex101.com/r/mI5uI0/2 although this regex is not 100% save, html parser would be better. Here time1 and time2 are optional and the order has to be preserved.

Comment: Thanx. I think I could use Html Parsing (using XPaths); I'm hoping there won't be a big drop in performance since I'd be extracting informations one by one on the same source string. :-)

Comment: @DonMadrino That's a good idea. One improvement on the regex would be to replace ' and " with ['"] so you can have both or instead of space accept any amount of whitespaces etc. but it will never be 100% save. Thanks for accepting.