# Regex Match Optional Group Surrounded by Any Character Grouping

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match an optional group that can be preceded and followed by any number of characters.  The entire pattern also has a required beginning and ending match, but the middle match is optional.

I started with this, which works when the middle group is required:

```
string text = @"blah blah foo This is a test blah.  the test does not work. bar";
string  requiredBlah = @"(foo).*?(blah).*?(bar)";
Match m = Regex.Match(text, requiredBlah);
```

Results are "foo", "blah", "bar".

However, when the middle group is optional, I guess the mechanisms of the regex engine prefer to not match the middle group.

```
string optionalBlah = @"(foo).*?(blah)?.*?(bar)";
```

Results:  "foo", "", bar".

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772440/regex-force-parsing-optional-groups) says that I can capture the middle optional group if there are delimiters before and after the optional group, but that is not my situation.

I could skip the optional group entirely and use `string.Contains("blah")`, but I'm wondering if there is a purely regex solution to this kind of problem.  My goal is to design regular expressions that match a generic pattern, with multiple optional parts, so that I can determine which parts of the pattern are missing.

Comment: It is absolutely doable. This website helped me a lot creating them:https://regex101.com

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jV6xO7/1
?

Comment: Having asterisks in the middle of a pattern doesn't work very well with Regex.  Having one asterisks at end of a pattern will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is quite common. The second dot matching pattern grabs the `blah` and does not have to yield it back to `(blah)?` as it is optional (see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(foo)(.*%3f)(blah)%3f(.*%3f)(bar)&i=blah+blah+foo+This+is+a+test+blah.++the+test+does+not+work.+bar) where I added capture groups to the original regex to show what group matches `blah`).

[image]

The simplest solution is to enclose the lazy `.*?` pattern and the `(blah)` capturing group into an optional non-capturing group (i.e. `(?:.*?(blah))?`) to make the regex engine try matching the group pattern at least once (= *greedily*):

```
(foo)(?:.*?(blah))?.*?(bar)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28foo%29%28%3F%3A.*%3F%28blah%29%29%3F.*%3F%28bar%29&i=blah%20blah%20foo%20This%20is%20a%20test%20blah.%20%20the%20test%20does%20not%20work.%20bar%0D%0Ablah%20blah%20foo%20This%20is%20a%20test.%20%20the%20test%20works.%20bar). Here, `(foo)` captures `foo` in Group 1, `(?:.*?(blah))?` matches an optional sequence of 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible and then captures `blah` into Group 2, and then `.*?(bar)` matches 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible and then captures `bar` into Group 3:

[image]

Another solution is to restrict the dot matching with a lookahead (using a so called [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)):

```
(foo)(?:(?!blah).)*(blah)?.*?(bar)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(foo)(%3F%3A(%3F!blah).)*(blah)%3F.*%3F(bar)&i=blah%20blah%20foo%20This%20is%20a%20test%20blah.%20%20the%20test%20does%20not%20work.%20bar). The `(?:(?!blah).)*` pattern matches any text up to the first `blah`. (If it is at the end of the pattern, it may also match up to the end of string.)

[image]

Comment: That did it. I previously tried a couple of variations of a negative lookahead, but was unable to wrap my limited brain around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using the `or` operator for both cases

```
(foo).*?(blah).*?(bar)|(foo).*?(bar)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI9iT9/1)

Comment: Then you'd better use named groups. Also, that way a regex pattern can grow huge if there are three or four alternatives and the pattern itself is long.

Comment: I wanted to avoid an 'or because my patterns will eventually be quite long, with multiple optional match groups.